# Unable to Create a Ruby Hash inside a Class

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a simple Ruby class but I am getting stuck. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
class Dock

 @ships = Hash.new(false) 

 def initialize()
 end

 def store(ship, pier)
    @ships[pier] = ship
 end

end

yathi = Dock.new
yathi.store("test", 12)
```

But when I try to run this by running this in Terminal:

```
ruby test.rb
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
test.rb:8:in `'store': undefined method `'[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:13
```

It does work when if I rewrite it like this:

```
@ships = {pier => ship}
```

But this creates a new hash everytime with just one value which I don't want. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `@ships = Hash.new(false)` inside the `initialize` method. When you put it outside the `initialize` method you are defining a class level instance variable instead. Check out [this](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) writeup if you want to know more.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. And now I understand that when I was using the {} notation it was creating a totally new hash independent of the initial @ships which I defined.

Answer (score 2):

Try initializing the hash inside the "initialize" method so that it is a member of *instances of the Dock class* instead of a member of the *Dock class itself*:

```ruby
class Dock
  def initialize()
    @ships = Hash.new(false) # <-- Define @ships as an instance variable.
  end
  def store(ship, pier)
    @ships[pier] = ship
  end
end
```